# Objects with features dataset

Tags: object, dataset

I'm searching for an objects dataset for Phd purposes. I'm working on objects recognition.
This dataset should contain a big number of images containg for each object, the whole object and others images containg several attributes (features) of the same object of the dataset.
(exemple : dog + head + tail + paws )
Any suggestions please??

Comment: hi, were you able to find the dataset ?